# Complex Discrete Form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I was studying mechanical vibrations and had a doubt at the following differential equation as mentioned in the figure below[image]

Here the above equation has the exact solution in the form of  $ cos(wt) $ but the discrete solution will have an additional  $ sin(wt) $ term also. How is this exact complex discrete form prooved?

I have tried to represent $ cos(wt) $ in terms of hyperbolic exponential terms, to get a discrete form, but when I tried to take the increments in "n", the solution seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I general, the solution of the differential equation $y'' + \omega^2 y=0$ is a linear combination of two independent components: $cos(\omega x)$ and $sin(\omega x)$. For this particular problem, the constraint $y'(0)=0$  rules out $sin(\omega x)$ from the solution.

Comment: so in the complex discrete form, is it a general solution or specific solution for this problem?

Comment: The complex exponential form is the general solution. If the constraint of initial speed was different from zero, then the solution would include the sine function as well.

Comment: one last doubt is that, what will be the exponential for the above equation with the above conditions in discrete complex form?

Comment: This differential equation is of 2nd order and it has two independent solutions. In this case, they are $e^{i\omega x}$ and $e^{-i\omega x}$ . The general solution is a linear combination of these with arbitrary coefficients, and the solution that satisfies the initial conditions is a linear combination with specific coefficients, such that the result fits in the constraints. For this particular case, the solution($cosx$) could be written as $\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\omega x} + e^{-i\omega x})$ , though the trigonometric form is perhaps more useful.

Comment: @daniel I am sorry there is a typo in the formula on the last line of the previous comment. Please consider this formula for the solution instead: $\frac{1}{2} y_0 (e^{i \omega x}+e^{-i \omega x})$